# How can I check to see if a Dialog is closed?

Tags: java

Is there a way to tell if a Dialog has been closed  in java, here is bear minimum code:

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(jframe);
JButton jbutton = new JButton("Press to stuff");

jframe.add(jbutton);

jbutton.addActionListener((e)->{

    methodStuff(dialog);
    //stuff to do after dialog has been closed
}
```

And somewhere in this so called "methodStuff"

```
...
dialog.dispose();
...
```

How can I check that this line: "dialog.dispose();" happened?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener to the dialog and put the code you want to execute inside the override method...

## Example:

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(jframe);
JButton jbutton = new JButton("Press to stuff");
dialog .addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            //your code here!!!
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, however for some reason windowClosing didn't work so i found the WindowAdapter javadoc and decided to use windowClosed which worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Add window listener and window adapter for tracking this

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, just keep a boolean in the parent class and just change its status(true or false) for the dialog. 
Eg- Change the value to *true* when dialog appears and change the value back to *false* just before the *dispose()*;.